# fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Tags: git, ssh, cpanel

I am trying to clone repository from remote git.
I have shared hosting and I have created new repository in my cPanel.

I have created new pair of ssh keys using `ssh-keygen`
Then imported key in cpanel from "SSH Access".

To connect from local machine, I have added following commands on git bash

`$ eval ssh-agent`

`Agent pid 1286`

`$ ssh-add id_rsa_prasad_local`

`Identity added: id_rsa_prasad_local (PG@DESKTOP-HAFRU7M)`

`$ git clone ssh://hostcd1m@mywebsitename.com/home/hostcd1m/test`

then it is showing error as below

> Cloning into 'test'...
>
> ssh: connect to host mywebsitename.com port 22:
> Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: "*Connection timed out*" Network problem. Not a git or ssh authentication problem. Try `ping mywebsitename.com`, `ssh hostcd1m@mywebsitename.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain name was not pointed to server's host name. 
so if I try to clone with server hostname , I able to clone it successfully.

example :
`git clone ssh://hostcd1m@ServerHostName.Net/home/hostcd1m/test`

so I pointed my domain name 'mywebsite.com' to server hostname 'ServerHostName.Net'.

Answer (score 1):

I've wasted a day troubleshooting this problem. The solution for me is to use the ip address instead of the domain name.

So it's

```
git clone ssh://[user_name]@[ip_address]:[port]/path
```

You can find the ip address from CPanel's "Server Information" section.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have that (in an enterprise environment) when SSH is not allowed, meaning the network route does allow

- port 22 to be visible for inbound connections (when the server is in the same LAN).
- port 22 to be used for outbound connection (when the server is in a WAN, outside the local network)

Depending on your own environment, check with an admin if SSH connections are allowed.

Comment: thank you @VonC for you answer, as I said, I am using shared hosting. and port 22 is not open for my shared hosting. host provider suggest me to upgrade the hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue recently, but non of the other suggestions seemed to resolve for me. In my case, the issue was with the algorithm used to generate my SSH keys - rsa. This *had* been working, but stopped (deprecation, I believe).

Checked with:

```
ssh -vvv <server> -p <portnumber>
```

Output included the fact that there was no mutual signature algorithm:

```
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

SSH keys were then regenerated (in the default location) using ECDSA algorithm:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521
```

And finally, the public key re-added on the site. After this, I stopped getting the above error.